# Compute Vega and Delta in R

Tags: options, programming, greeks

I am trying to compute greeks for a large sample of CEO compensation contracts in R. However, my vega computations all result in a value of zero.

In doing so, I follow [Core and Guay [2002]](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3542266#metadata_info_tab_contents):

[image]

Here is some a snapshot of one contract that contains multiple options:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(prccf = rep(36.55, 15),
            Xc = 28:42,
            maturity = seq(0.5, 7.5, by = (1/2)),
            rf = rnorm(15, 4.5, 0.25), 
            d = rep(0.025, 15),
            sigma = rep(0.30, 15))
```

I compute Z:

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate(Zc = (log(prccf / Xc) + maturity * (rf - d + sigma^2 / 2)) / (sigma * sqrt(maturity)))
```

Then I take the first derivative of the Black-Scholes option value, with respect to `prccf` and `sigma`:

```
deriv(~ ((prccf * exp(-d * maturity) * pnorm(Zc)) - (Xc * exp(-rf * maturity) * pnorm(Zc - sigma * sqrt(maturity)))), c("prccf", "sigma"))
```

which gives:

```
delta = exp(-d * maturity) * pnorm(Zc)
vega = Xc * exp(-rf * maturity) * (dnorm(Zc - sigma * sqrt(maturity)) * sqrt(maturity))
```

So:

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate(delta = exp(-d * maturity) * pnorm(Zc),
       vega = Xc * exp(-rf * maturity) * (dnorm(Zc - sigma * sqrt(maturity)) * sqrt(maturity)))
```

But then all values for vega are zero. This happens irrespective of the parameters.

The vega part becomes zero when it gets multiplied with the normal density function: `dnorm(Zc - sigma * sqrt(maturity))`, because `Zc` contains relatively high values for the normal distribution, so it results in 0. Then the whole line gets multiplied by 0, resulting in 0s as final values as well.

I do not really see how I can fix this, since Zc does capture the right value. (The "delta code" is correct, because I can compare it to another dataset (correlation of 0.999).)

This also happens when I rely on packages instead of manually computing it, e.g.:

```
library(derivmkts)

bsopt(s = df$prccf,
      k = df$Xc,
      v = df$sigma,
      r = df$rf,
      tt = df$maturity,
      d = df$d)[['Call']][c('Delta', 'Vega'), ]
```

Can someome help me with this issue? I got stuck, especially because the delta part *is* correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your `rf` values are right? If `15` is to mean 15%, then write it as `0.15`.

Comment: That's it. I guess after many hours of coding such a tiny mistake becomes invisible.. ```rf = rnorm(15, 4.5, 0.25)``` should indeed be ```rf = rnorm(15, 0.045, 0.0025)```. Thanks!